# Kalkun error - Initialisation failed, stopping Gammu smsd: Unknown error. (UNKNOWN[27])

Tags: android

I have a problem with my Kalkun. 
    I ussualy use the commands bellow:
    *gammu-smsd -c /etc/gammu-smsdrc -d*
    and i test if everything it's ok with
    *tail -f /var/log/gammu.log*

```
But something's wrong and when i enter
*# tail -f /var/log/gammu.log*
i get this:

*tail -f /var/log/gammu.log
Fri 2015/08/28 11:10:22 gammu-smsd[1516]: SHM token: 0xffffffffce0412f3 (-838593805)
Fri 2015/08/28 11:10:22 gammu-smsd[1516]: Warning: No PIN code in /etc/gammu-smsdrc file
Fri 2015/08/28 11:10:22 gammu-smsd[1516]: CommTimeout=30, SendTimeout=30, ReceiveFrequency=0, ResetFrequency=0, HardResetFrequency=0
Fri 2015/08/28 11:10:22 gammu-smsd[1516]: checks: CheckSecurity=1, CheckBattery=1, CheckSignal=1
Fri 2015/08/28 11:10:22 gammu-smsd[1516]: mode: Send=1, Receive=1
Fri 2015/08/28 11:10:22 gammu-smsd[1516]: deliveryreport = log
Fri 2015/08/28 11:10:22 gammu-smsd[1516]: phoneid = mdsms
Fri 2015/08/28 11:10:22 gammu-smsd[1531]: Error connecting to database!
Fri 2015/08/28 11:10:22 gammu-smsd[1531]: Error code: 2002, Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
Fri 2015/08/28 11:10:22 gammu-smsd[1531]: Initialisation failed, stopping Gammu smsd: Unknown error. (UNKNOWN[27])*

Can you help me please? 
Thank you!
```